# Как убрать анимацию ?

Tags: jquery, анимация

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.click').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    }
});
```

Что бы просто hide и show.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.entry').hide();
$('.click').click(function(e){
    if(e.target.nodeName != 'A'){
        $(this).next().toggle("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: Не совсем так.

Comment: а как должно быть?